# How to compile a cython module that has __version__ version information

Tags: python, cython, python-wheel

I am compiling a cython module using
`python3 setup.py bdist_wheel` and I have a `setup.py` which contains

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
  name=setup_name,
  version='2.1',...
```

Now I would like to be able to print the version number from a function within my module, and/or have the common `module.__version__` information. How do I go about doing that? I would like to simply use the version from setup, not introduce a new variable or hardcode this information twice.

Comment: I don't think setuptools provides any features to let you do this, but some more modern build systems (like [hatch](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/version/)) do.